# JFrame does hot change size on frame.pack()

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I have a JFrame with JPanels in it, one of which is a JTabbedPane. It is created with Intellij Ideea form designer and the formPanel has prefferedSize set to something like 1200x800 which fits the content well.

The user can increase fonts and all the element fonts are increased. When this happens some elements do not fit in the window anymore. I tried calling frame.pack() but the frame keeps the same size.

What would be the standard approach to this?

Comment: _and the formPanel has prefferedSize set to something like 1200x800_ Forcing preferred size is the best way to run into the issue you mention.

Comment: After removing preferredSize it resizes on frame.pack(). Please add the comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid forcing the preferred size of components should solve your problem. Forcing preferred size always leads to those kind of issues.

For the basic Swing components (such as `JLabel`, `JTextfield`, `JButton`, etc...), the preferred size is dynamically computed (by the UI of the component) and will take into account the font that is used.